# Nmap scan different (?) subnet (ARP request)

Tags: wireshark, arp, nmap

Well met!

I have two machines and a switch, one machine has the address "192.168.233.1" the other has "192.168.1.1". How could I scan, using nmap, the range 192.168.1.1-254 from the 233.1 machine? I want to be able to see only the requests to 192.168.1.1 in Wireshark.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hosts must be interconnected by a `gateway` (assuming their subnet mask is a `/24`).

If the gateway exists, the two subnet can reach each other and you can use nmap normally (e.g. `nmap -sP 192.168.1.1-254`)

Then if you wanna see only traffic toward the host `192.168.1.1`, put `ip.addr == 192.168.1.1` as filter on `wireshark`

Comment: I don't have access to a router, and it's supposedly doable without. Isn't there something that can be done with virtual machines? Or perhaps a third computer?

Comment: Just two computers connected with a switch.

Comment: can you put virtual address on `1.1` host (let's say `192.168.233.254`), enable `ip_forwarding` and set `192.168.233.254` as gateway on `233.1` host? in a nutshell, we're turning the `1.1` host into a gateway between two networks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is done here. Could the same be done with three computers instead of a virtual machine on one of the two?

Comment: What you need is a way to make 192.168.233.X subnet talk with the 192.168.1.X one. You need a device with TWO ip addresses, one per subnet, in order to route traffic between the two networks